# Can a public school "edit" a transcript from a private institution?

Tags: california, education

I've got quite the interesting story. Long story short, I'm enrolled at summer school with a private, nonprofit institution that has an agreement with my school district that allows grades from summer school to appear on official school district transcripts for credit. The summer school has a policy that there are no excused absences, even for illness (diagnosed by a state-licensed physician). Due to this, my grade in the class is extremely low.

Can this public school district change the grade I receive from the summer school class to one they believe is representative? The instructor of the summer school class is also a instructor within the school district, if that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt it. Your best bet is to file an appeal.